# Looping over arrays, printing both index and value

Tags: bash

I want to do something like this:

```
foo=( )
foo[0]="bar"
foo[35]="baz"
for((i=0;i<${#foo[@]};i++))
do
    echo "$i: ${foo[$i]}"
done
# Output:
# 0: bar
# 1:
```

Then i tried to loop through it using for in:

```
foo=( )
foo[0]="bar"
foo[35]="baz"
for i in ${foo[@]}
do
    echo "?: $i"
done
# Output:
# ?: bar
# ?: naz
```

but here I don't know the index value.

I know you could something like

```
foo=( )
foo[0]="bar"
foo[35]="baz"
declare -p foo
# Output:
# declare -a foo='([0]="bar" [35]="baz")'
```

but, can't you do it in another way?

Answer (score 480, accepted):

You would find the array keys with `"${!foo[@]}"` ([reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)), so:

```
for i in "${!foo[@]}"; do 
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${foo[$i]}"
done
```

Which means that indices will be in `$i` while the elements themselves have to be accessed via `${foo[$i]}`

Comment: Important note, while iterable, a space separated list of words is _not_ an array. Wrap it like so `(a b c)` to convert it to an array.

Comment: The use of `[@]` and double quotes means it's not a "space separated list of words". You get the list of actual array keys, even if the individual keys contain whitespace.

Comment: @glennjackman can you explain this more `The use of [@] and double quotes means it's not a "space separated list of words"`

Comment: `"${foo[@]}"` takes the (array) variable `foo` and expands it as an array, maintaining the identity of its elements, i.e., not splitting them on whitespace. If `foo=(x 'y z')`, then `f "${foo[@]}"` calls `f` with two arguments, `x` and `'y z'`. Metadata queries like `"${!foo[@]}"` and `"${#foo[@]}"` similarly act on `foo` as an array.

Comment: Right answer, but that [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is inscrutable. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979315/1230197) helpfully just explains: "`"${!foo[@]}"` is the list of all the indexes set in the array".

Comment: Does this also work if the array is `$@`, i.e. the argument array passed to any function or script?

Comment: Did you try it? What did you see?

Comment: @glennjackman `echo "${!@}"` just prints nothing. `echo "${![@]}"` says "${![@]}: bad substitution". `echo "$!@"` prints `@`. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: So that's your answee: you need to use `for ((i=1; i <= $#; i++)) ; do echo "${!i}" ;done` to use the positional parameter indices. Or simply `for param; do echo "$param" ; done`

Comment: What if I have a function and want to print both index and value in an array. Since, my function is generic, I can not use array name. How to solve this case? Thanks

Comment: Please ask a new question

Comment: This works better than doing a for loop against ${arrray[@]} on its own as I am finding this splits up strings contained in the array

Comment: @JohnSohn, you need to quote the array expansion for just this reason: `for item in "${array[@]}"` -- and then quote `"$item"` where you use it.

Comment: @glennjackman I really really hate the bash shell lol Thank you.

Answer (score 42):

you can always use iteration param:

```sh
ITER=0
for I in ${FOO[@]}
do  
    echo ${I} ${ITER}
    ITER=$(expr $ITER + 1)
done
```

Comment: `((ITER++))` in modern bash

Comment: Why post-increment ? You only want the value incremented, hence ((++ITER)) is more directly a statement of what you want done ....

Comment: No, not "ALWAYS". A hash  can have "holes", which means not all numbers are an index. In your example the ${ITER} is not always the index of ${I}.

Answer (score 28):

```
INDEX=0
for i in $list; do 
    echo ${INDEX}_$i
    let INDEX=${INDEX}+1
done
```

Comment: I liked the conciseness of the answer and strategy. For anyone wondering this is bash and the strat is you just keep track of the array index on your own.

Answer (score 12):

## Simple *one line* trick for dumping array

I've added one value with spaces:

```bash
foo=([12]="bar" [42]="foo bar baz" [35]="baz")
```

For a quick dump of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arrays or *associative arrays* I use

**This one line command:**

```bash
paste <(printf "%s\n" "${!foo[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}")
```

Will render:

```
12  bar
35  baz
42  foo bar baz
```

#### Explained

- `printf "%s\n" "${!foo[@]}"` will print all *keys* separated by a *newline*,
- `printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}"` will print all *values* separated by a *newline*,
- `paste <(cmd1) <(cmd2)` will merge output of `cmd1` and `cmd2` line by line.

#### Tunning

This could be tunned by `-d` switch:

```bash
paste -d : <(printf "%s\n" "${!foo[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}")
```

```
12:bar
35:baz
42:foo bar baz
```

or even:

```bash
paste -d = <(printf "foo[%s]\n" "${!foo[@]}") <(printf "'%s'\n" "${foo[@]}")
```

```
foo[12]='bar'
foo[35]='baz'
foo[42]='foo bar baz'
```

#### Associative array will work same:

```bash
declare -A bar=([foo]=snoopy [bar]=nice [baz]=cool [foo bar]='Hello world!')
paste -d = <(printf "bar[%s]\n" "${!bar[@]}") <(printf '"%s"\n' "${bar[@]}")
```

```
bar[foo bar]="Hello world!"
bar[foo]="snoopy"
bar[bar]="nice"
bar[baz]="cool"
```

#### Issue with *newlines* or special chars

Unfortunely, there is at least one condition making this not work anymore: when variable do contain newline:

```bash
foo[17]=$'There is one\nnewline'
```

Command `paste` will merge line-by-line, so output will become wrong:

```bash
paste -d = <(printf "foo[%s]\n" "${!foo[@]}") <(printf "'%s'\n" "${foo[@]}")
```

```
foo[12]='bar'
foo[17]='There is one
foo[35]=newline'
foo[42]='baz'
='foo bar baz'
```

For this work, you could use `%q` instead of `%s` in second `printf` command (and whipe quoting):

```bash
paste -d = <(printf "foo[%s]\n" "${!foo[@]}") <(printf "%q\n" "${foo[@]}")
```

Will render perfect ( **and reusable!** ):

```
foo[12]=bar
foo[17]=$'There is one\nnewline'
foo[35]=baz
foo[42]=foo\ bar\ baz
```

From `man bash`:

> ```
>           %q     causes  printf  to output the corresponding argument in a
>                  format that can be reused as shell input.
> ```

### Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), without *loop* and without *fork*

Another way of doing this by rendering a *format string* for `printf` command:

```bash
printf -v fmt '[%d]=%%q\\n' "${!foo[@]}";printf "$fmt" "${foo[@]}"
```

```
[12]=bar
[17]=$'There is one\nnewline'
[35]=baz
[42]=foo\ bar\ baz
```

Note: by using `printf -v` you could do a *string* thak you could use to define a *new variable*:

```bash
printf -v fmt '[%d]=%%q\\n' "${!foo[@]}"
printf -v asString "$fmt" "${foo[@]}"
declare -a "newVar=($asString)"
declare -p newVar
```

```
declare -a newVar=([12]="bar" [17]=$'There is one\nnewline' [35]="baz" [42]="foo bar baz")
```

But for *Associative arrays*, you have to care about presence of percent sign in index names:

```bash
bar['100%var']=42
varIdx=("${!bar[@]}")
printf -v fmt '[%q]=%%q\\n' "${varIdx[@]//\%/%%}"
printf "$fmt" "${bar[@]}"
```

```
[100%var]=42
[foo]=snoopy
[bar]=nice
[baz]=cool
[foo\ bar]=Hello\ world\!
```

Then same, for creating a new *associative array*:

```
printf -v asString "$fmt" "${bar[@]}"
declare -A "newAssoc=($asString)"
declare -p newAssoc
```

```
declare -A newAssoc=([100%var]="42" [foo]="snoopy" [bar]="nice" [baz]="cool" ["foo bar"]="Hello world!" )
```

## By using a function:

```
dumpArray() {
    local -n _ary=$1
    local _idx
    local -i _idlen=0
    for _idx in "${!_ary[@]}"; do
        _idlen=" ${#_idx} >_idlen ? ${#_idx} : _idlen "
    done
    for _idx in "${!_ary[@]}"; do
        printf "%-*s: %s\n" "$_idlen" "$_idx" \
            "${_ary["$_idx"]//$'\n'/$'\n\e['${_idlen}C  }"
    done
}
```

Then now:

```
dumpArray foo
12: bar
17: There is one
    newline
35: baz
42: foo bar baz

dumpArray bar
foo    : snoopy
bar    : nice
baz    : cool
foo bar: Hello world!
```

### About UTF-8 format output

From [UTF-8 string length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31009961/1765658), adding:

```
strU8DiffLen() { local chLen=${#1} LANG=C LC_ALL=C;return $((${#1}-chLen));}
```

or better, using `printf -v _ '%s%n'`

Then

```
dumpArray() {
    local -n _ary=$1
    local _idx
    local -i _idlen=0 _idbytes
    for _idx in "${!_ary[@]}"; do
        _idlen=" ${#_idx} >_idlen ? ${#_idx} : _idlen "
    done
    for _idx in "${!_ary[@]}"; do
        printf -v _ '%s%n' "$_idx" _idbytes
        printf "%-*s: %s\n" $((_idbytes-${#_idx}+_idlen)) "$_idx" \
            "${_ary["$_idx"]//$'\n'/$'\n\e['${_idlen}C  }"
    done
}
```

Demo:

```
foo=([12]="bar" [42]="foo bar baz" [35]="baz")
declare -A bar=([foo]=snoopy [bar]=nice [baz]=cool [foo bar]='Hello world!')

foo[17]=$'There is one\nnewline'
LANG=fr.UTF-8 printf -v bar[déjà]  $'%(%a %d %b\n%Y\n%T)T' -1

dumpArray bar
déjà   : ven 24 déc
         2021
         08:36:05
foo    : snoopy
bar    : nice
baz    : cool
foo bar: Hello world!

dumpArray foo
12: bar
17: There is one
    newline
35: baz
42: foo bar baz
```

## See also

- [Converting a Bash array into a delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471141/1765658)

Comment: My up vote for `printf "%q\n" "${var[@]}"` *newline* was my problem!

Answer (score 7):

In bash 4, you can use associative arrays:

```
declare -A foo
foo[0]="bar"
foo[35]="baz"

# for Zsh, change this to: for key in "${(k)foo[@]}"
for key in "${!foo[@]}"
do
    echo "key: $key, value: ${foo[$key]}"
done

# output
# $ key: 0, value bar.
# $ key: 35, value baz.
```

In bash 3, this works (also works in zsh):

```
map=( )
map+=("0:bar")
map+=("35:baz")

for keyvalue in "${map[@]}" ; do
    key=${keyvalue%%:*}
    value=${keyvalue#*:}
    echo "key: $key, value $value."
done
```

Comment: trying the bash 3 version (in zsh), it echoes out the `value` for both key and value..

Comment: I verified the second version works fine for me in Zsh 5.8, however, the first version is preferable if you're using Zsh. Replace `for key in "${!foo[@]}"` with `for key in "${(k)foo[@]}"` for Zsh.

Answer (score 1):

```
users=("kamal" "jamal" "rahim" "karim" "sadia")
index=()
t=-1

for i in ${users[@]}; do
  t=$(( t + 1 ))
  if [ $t -eq 0 ]; then
    for j in ${!users[@]}; do
      index[$j]=$j
    done
  fi
  echo "${index[$t]} is $i"
done
```

Comment: This is wrong! Inner loop is useless and could drive to wrong results!