# Converting a Bash array into a delimited string

Tags: arrays, string, bash, csv

I would like to know the following;

1. Why the given non-working example doesn't work.
2. If there are any other cleaner methods than those given in working example.

*Non-working example*

```
> ids=(1 2 3 4);echo ${ids[*]// /|}
1 2 3 4
> ids=(1 2 3 4);echo ${${ids[*]}// /|}
-bash: ${${ids[*]}// /|}: bad substitution
> ids=(1 2 3 4);echo ${"${ids[*]}"// /|}
-bash: ${"${ids[*]}"// /|}: bad substitution
```

*Working example*

```
> ids=(1 2 3 4);id="${ids[@]}";echo ${id// /|}
1|2|3|4
> ids=(1 2 3 4); lst=$( IFS='|'; echo "${ids[*]}" ); echo $lst
1|2|3|4
```

In context, the delimited string to be used in a [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) command for further parsing.

Comment: `${${ids[*]}// /|}` is a syntax error, that's all. Dunno what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Trying to achieve variable substitution in 1 hop, it was never going to work...

Comment: Related: [How can I join elements of an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527049/6862601).

Comment: You can use [`paste`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75373857/52499).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## Array to strings in `bash`

### 1. Array to string, by using `$IFS`

Because parentheses are used to delimit an **array**, not a **string:**

```
ids="1 2 3 4";echo ${ids// /|}
1|2|3|4
```

Some samples: Populating `$ids` with two strings:  `a b` and `c d`

```
ids=("a b" "c d" e\ f)

echo ${ids[*]// /|}
a|b c|d e|f

IFS='|';echo "${ids[*]}";IFS=$' \t\n'
a b|c d|e f
```

... and finally:

```
IFS='|';echo "${ids[*]// /|}";IFS=$' \t\n'
a|b|c|d|e|f
```

Where array is assembled, separated by 1st char of `$IFS`, but with space replaced by `|` in each element of array.

When you do:

```
id="${ids[@]}"
```

you transfer the string build from the merging of the **array** `ids` by a space to a new variable of type **string**.

**Note:** when `"${ids[@]}"` give a *space-separated* string, `"${ids[*]}"` (with a star `*` instead of the at sign `@`) will render a string separated by the **first character of `$IFS`**.

what `man bash` says:

```
man -Len -Pcol\ -b bash | sed -ne '/^ *IFS /{N;N;p;q}'
   IFS    The  Internal  Field  Separator  that  is used for word splitting
          after expansion and to split  lines  into  words  with  the  read
          builtin command.  The default value is ``<space><tab><newline>''.
```

Playing with `$IFS`:

```
printf "%q\n" "$IFS"
$' \t\n'
```

Literally a `space`, a `tabulation` and *(meaning or)* a `line-feed`. So, while the first character is a space. the use of `*` will do the same as `@`.

**But**:

```
{
    IFS=: read -a array < <(echo root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash)
    
    echo 1 "${array[@]}"
    echo 2 "${array[*]}"
    OIFS="$IFS" IFS=:
    echo 3 "${array[@]}"
    echo 4 "${array[*]}"
    IFS="$OIFS"
}
1 root x 0 0 root /root /bin/bash
2 root x 0 0 root /root /bin/bash
3 root x 0 0 root /root /bin/bash
4 root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

**Note:** The line `IFS=: read -a array < <(...)` will use `:` as separator, without setting `$IFS` permanently. This is because output line `#2` present spaces as separators.

#### 1.1 Using function, *localize* `$IFS`

To just print array

```
printArry() {
    local IFS="$1"
    shift
    echo "$*"
}        

printArry @ "${ids[@]}"
a b@c d@e f
```

Or to merge array *in place*.

```
mergeArry() {
    local IFS="$1"
    local -n _array_to_merge=$2
    _array_to_merge=("${_array_to_merge[*]}")
}

declare -p ids
declare -a ids=([0]="a b" [1]="c d" [2]="e f")

mergeArry '#' ids
declare -p ids
declare -a ids=([0]="a b#c d#e f")
```

### 2. Array of strings to array of strings (`[@]` vs `[*]`)

There is a notable difference between:

- `"$@"` and `"${var[@]}"` result in an array of strings
- `"$*"` and `"${var[*]}"` result in an unique string

Read carefully: `man '-Pless +/Special\ Parameters' bash`

For this, I will **quote** each argument in order to not be splitted by `$IFS` at *command line expansion*, using **double-quotes** to permit *variable expansion*.

```
ids=('a b c' 'd e f' 'g h i')
```

```bash
printf '<< %s >>\n' "${ids[@]// /|}"
```

```
<< a|b|c >>
<< d|e|f >>
<< g|h|i >>
```

```bash
printf '<< %s >>\n' "${ids[*]// /|}"
```

```
<< a|b|c d|e|f g|h|i >>
```

Where:

- All spaces where replaced by pipes, in each strings
- All string where merged into one string, separated by 1st `$IFS` character.

```bash
( IFS='@'; printf '<< %s >>\n' "${ids[*]// /|}" )
<< a|b|c@d|e|f@g|h|i >>
```

Note: `${var// /something}` will replace every *spaces* by *something*, but `${var[*]}` will merge array by using only one 1st character:

```
( IFS='FOO'; printf '<< %s >>\n' "${ids[*]// / BAR }" )
<< a BAR b BAR cFd BAR e BAR fFg BAR h BAR i >>
```

And yes: by using `${var// / ... }`, you could replace **1 space** by anthing you want, including more spaces.

### 3. Array to string, by using `printf`

As we see, using `$IFS` is limited to only 1 character. If you need to use more characters to be inserted between your fields. You have to use `printf`:

```
ids=("a b" "c d" e\ f)
sep=" long separator "
printf -v string "%s$sep" "${ids[@]}"
echo "${string%$sep}"
a b long separator c d long separator e f
```

**Note:** this syntax work but is something *limited*, see further!

#### 3.1 Array to string, by using `printf`, into a function

In order to support special characters as `%` or `*` in *`separator`*, the function have to prevents

- `%` to be interpreted by `printf` (`printf '%%'` will render a `%`) and
- `*` to be interpreted by *parameter expansion*, for this `$sep` have to be double quoted.

```
printArry() {
    local sep=$1 string
    shift
    printf -v string "%s${sep//%/%%}" "$@"
    echo "${string%"$sep"}"
}
```

```
printArry ' long separator ' "${ids[@]}"
a b long separator c d long separator e f

printArry '*' "${ids[@]}"
a b*c d*e f

printArry '%' "${ids[@]}"
a b%c d%e f
```

Or to merge array *in place*.

```
mergeArry() {
    local sep=$1 string
    local -n _array_to_merge=$2
    printf -v string "%s${sep//%/%%}" "${_array_to_merge[@]}"
    _array_to_merge=("${string%"$sep"}")
}

mergeArry ' another separator ' ids
declare -p ids
declare -a ids=([0]="a b another separator c d another separator e f")

ids=("a b" "c d" e\ f)
mergeArry '*' ids
declare -p ids
declare -a ids=([0]="a b*c d*e f")
```

### 4. Merge array to string using `bash`'s *parameter expansion*

Yet another way [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TMTOWTDI): But as for working, we have to *empty* `$IFS`, I prefer to use this in a function for *localize* `$IFS`.

```
printArry () { 
    local -n _array_to_print=$2
    local IFS=
    local _string_to_print="${_array_to_print[*]/#/"$1"}"
    echo "${_string_to_print/#"$1"}"
}
```

Note you could replace `#` by `%` as

- "${_array_to_merge[*]/#/$1}" will replace *begin of string* by `$1`, while
- "${_array_to_merge[*]/%/$1}" will replace *end of string* by `$1`, then
- "${_array_to_merge/#"$1"}" will replace *$1 located at begin of string* by *nothing*, or
- "${_array_to_merge/%"$1"}" will replace *$1 located at end of string* by *nothing*.

```
mergeArry () { 
    local -n _array_to_merge=$2
    local IFS=
    _array_to_merge=("${_array_to_merge[*]/#/"$1"}")
    _array_to_merge=("${_array_to_merge/#"$1"}")
}
```

#### 4.1 Little variant, based on length of separator:

```
printArry () { 
    local -n _array_to_print=$2
    local IFS=
    local _string_to_print="${_array_to_print[*]/#/"$1"}"
    echo "${_string_to_print:${#1}}"
}
```

```
mergeArry () { 
    local -n _array_to_merge=$2
    local IFS=
    _array_to_merge=("${_array_to_merge[*]/#/"$1"}")
    _array_to_merge=("${_array_to_merge:${#1}}")
}
```

Or

```
printArry () { 
    local -n _array_to_print=$2
    local IFS=
    local _string_to_print="${_array_to_print[*]/%/"$1"}"
    echo "${_string_to_print::-${#1}}"
}
```

### 5. Comparison

To do...

### See also

- [Looping over arrays, printing both index and value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59991764/1765658)

Comment: So it's both a typeof and variable substitution error given ${ is expecting a var of type string but receives neither. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 31):

You can use `printf` too, without any external commands or the need to manipulate IFS:

```
ids=(1 2 3 4)                     # create array
printf -v ids_d '|%s' "${ids[@]}" # yields "|1|2|3|4"
ids_d=${ids_d:1}                  # remove the leading '|'
```

Comment: This was simplest for me, as I had >1 character string to put in between the array elements, and in my case I didn't need to remove the "extra" either. Works delightfully!  `printf -v strng "'%s',\n" ${thearray[*]}`  :)

Comment: Agree, simplest to use. Additionally, it's also the user-friendlier option if you are using IDE with syntax highlighting, which won't pick up `eval`'d syntax as in [gniourf_gniourf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33389200/9788634).

Answer (score 17):

Your first question is already addressed in [F. Hauri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471141). Here's canonical way to join the elements of an array:

```
ids=( 1 2 3 4 )
IFS=\| eval 'lst="${ids[*]}"'
```

Some people will cry out loud that `eval` is evil, yet it's perfectly safe here, thanks to the single quotes. This only has advantages: there are no subshells, `IFS` is not globally modified, it will not trim trailing newlines, and it's very simple.

Answer (score 6):

An utility function to join arguments array into a delimited string:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Join arguments with delimiter
# @Params
# $1: The delimiter string
# ${@:2}: The arguments to join
# @Output
# >&1: The arguments separated by the delimiter string
array::join() {
  (($#)) || return 1 # At least delimiter required
  local -- delim="$1" str IFS=
  shift
  str="${*/#/$delim}" # Expands arguments with prefixed delimiter (Empty IFS)
  printf '%s\n' "${str:${#delim}}" # Echo without first delimiter
}

declare -a my_array=( 'Paris' 'Berlin' 'London' 'Brussel' 'Madrid' 'Oslo' )

array::join ', ' "${my_array[@]}"
array::join '*' {1..9} | bc # 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9=362880 Factorial 9

declare -a null_array=()

array::join '== Ultimate separator of nothing ==' "${null_array[@]}"
```

Output:

```
Paris, Berlin, London, Brussel, Madrid, Oslo
362880
```

Now with Bash 4.2+'s nameref variables, using sub-shells output capture is no longer needed.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ((BASH_VERSINFO[0] < 4 || (BASH_VERSINFO[0] == 4 && BASH_VERSINFO[0] < 2)))
then
  printf 'Bash version 4.2 or above required for nameref variables\n' >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Join arguments with delimiter
# @Params
# $1: The variable reference to receive the joined output
# $2: The delimiter string
# ${@:3}: The arguments to join
# @Output
array::join_to() {
  (($# > 1)) || return 1 # At least nameref and delimiter required
  local -n out="$1"
  local -- delim="$2" str IFS=
  shift 2
  str="${*/#/$delim}" # Expands arguments with prefixed delimiter (Empty IFS)
  # shellcheck disable=SC2034 # Nameref variable
  out="${str:${#delim}}" # Discards prefixed delimiter
}

declare -g result1 result2 result3
declare -a my_array=( 'Paris' 'Berlin' 'London' 'Brussel' 'Madrid' 'Oslo' )

array::join_to result1 ', ' "${my_array[@]}"
array::join_to result2 '*' {1..9}
result2=$((result2)) # Expands arythmetic expression

declare -a null_array=()

array::join_to result3 '== Ultimate separator of nothing ==' "${null_array[@]}"

printf '%s\n' "$result1" "$result2" "$result3"
```

Comment: Very handy, thanks! Perhaps `join` would be a more appropriate name, though, in line with how, _e.g._, [Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) and [Python's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) `join` functions work?

Comment: @TheDudeAbides Could not name it directly `join` because this conflict with an existing command name that join lines of files.

Comment: *\*facepalm\** - ah yes, of course. I forgot about [that](https://man.cx/join).

Comment: Nice tool! permitting variable length delimiter! But consider using nameref to pass result as a variable in order to prevent forks...

Comment: @F.Hauri now with a nameref version