# How to print a bash array on the same line

Tags: arrays, bash, printf, echo

I am reading in filetype data into a bash array and need to print its contents out on the same line with spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
declare -a myArray

readarray myArray < $1

echo "${myArray[@]}"
```

I try this and even with the echo -n flag it still prints on newlines, what am I missing, would printf work better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`readarray` retains the trailing newline in each array element. To strip them, use the `-t` option.

```
readarray -t myArray < "$1"
```

Answer (score 38):

Simple way to print in one line

```
echo "${myArray[*]}"
```

example:

```
myArray=(
one
two
three
four
[5]=five
)

echo "${myArray[*]}"

#Result
one two three four five
```

Comment: What if I wanted formatted output (e.g. comma separated list of single quoted strings)

Comment: @Prachi Use this   `echo $(IFS=',';echo "${myArray[*]// /|}";IFS=$'')` , link https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471141/5287072

Answer (score 7):

One way :

```
printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}" | paste -sd ' ' -
```

The `-` is not mandatory on Linux, but could be necessary on some Unices*

or simply :

```
printf '%s ' "${myArray[@]}"
```

Comment: Using * is affected by the first character of "$IFS", which by default it happens to be an space. Using `printf '%s ' "${myArray[@]}"` is more robust.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite trick is

`echo $(echo "${myArray[@]}")`

Comment: Invoking a subshell just for printing the array contents is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: Without the subshell I was getting a newline inserted where there should have been a space.

Answer (score 2):

@sorontar's solution posted in a comment was handy:

```
printf '%s ' "${myArray[@]}"
```

but in some places the leading space was unacceptable so I implemented this

```
local str
printf -v str ' %s' "${myArray[@]}"  # save to variable str without printing
printf '%s' "${str:1}"  # to remove the leading space
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the array elements coming from input, this is how you can

- create an array
- add elements to it
- then print the array in a single line

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a array
var=0
while read line
do
  array[var]=$line
  var=$((var+1))
done

# At this point, the user would enter text. EOF by itself ends entry.

echo ${array[@]}
```

Comment: I am not able to format the code part as a code. Someone help.