# How to add single quotes to every word in a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, csv

I Have a couple of arguments in my variable. I want to replace each variable with single quotes, separated by a comma.

```
var_list=emp location  branch.
```

I want my output like:

```
var_list='emp', 'location',  'branch'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using Bash parameter expansion

```
delimited="'${var_list//[[:space:]]/"','"}'"
```

If you have multiple spaces in the string, then use extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
delimited="'${var_list//+([[:space:]])/"','"}'"
```

## Using an array

```
words=($var_list)                           # create array from string, using word splitting
printf -v delimited ",'%s'" "${words[@]}"   # yields ",'one','two',..."
delimited=${delimited:1}                    # remove the leading ','
```

## Using a loop

```
delim=''
for word in $var_list; do                   # rely on word splitting by shell
  delimited="$delimited$delim'$word'"
  delim=","
done
```

---

Related:

- [Converting a Bash array into a delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49167382/6862601)
- [Bash Manual - Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Thanks, @codeforester, I am using Bash shell and I tried both the ways, it is solving my problem.

Comment: I use Bash shell, and I don't know why the first approach doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @codeforester
I tried the first approach

```
delimited="'${var_list//[[:space:]]/"','"}'"
```

but it doesn't work. I got

```
'word_1"', '"word_2"', '"word_3'
```

Then I revised to statement to

```
delimited="'${var_list//[[:space:]]/','}'"
```

It works correctly.

```
'word_1', 'word_2', 'word_3'
```

Comment: What is your original string?  I tried it on `var_list="one two three"` and I did get `'one','two','three'`.  What Bash version are you using?