# Bash yad ComboBox argument as an array

Tags: bash, zenity, yad

Does yad support an array sent as an argument to the ComboBox field?

Example:

```
yad --form --field="ComboBox:CB" One\!Two\!Three
```

Can I make it work with an array?

```
array=(one two three)
yad --form --field="ComboBox:CB" $array
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Converting a Bash array into a delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470413/converting-a-bash-array-into-a-delimited-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yad` does not support array as input for ComboBox natively. You'll have to convert your array to a `!` separated string.

You can do this by temporarily modifying your [IFS](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS) variable, like so :

```
array=(one two three)
yad --form --field="ComboBox:CB" $(IFS=! ; echo "${array[*]}")
```