# Length of string in bash

Tags: bash, variables, string-length

How do you get the length of a string stored in a variable and assign that to another variable?

```
myvar="some string"
echo ${#myvar}  
# 11
```

How do you set another variable to the output `11`?

Answer (score 376, accepted):

### UTF-8 string length

#### By using `wc`

by using `wc`, you could (from `man bc`):

> ```
>    -c, --bytes
>           print the byte counts
>
>    -m, --chars
>           print the character counts
> ```

So you could under [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) [shell](/questions/tagged/shell):

```sh
echo -n Généralité | wc -c
```

```
 13
```

```sh
echo -n Généralité | wc -m
```

```
 10
```

```sh
echo -n Généralité | wc -cm
```

```
 10      13
```

```sh
for string in Généralités Language Théorème Février  "Left: ←" "Yin Yang ☯";do
    strlens=$(echo -n "$string"|wc -mc)
    chrs=$((${strlens% *}))
    byts=$((${strlens#*$chrs }))
    printf " - %-*s is %2d chars length, but uses %2d bytes\n" \
        $(( 14 + $byts - $chrs )) "$string" $chrs $byts
done
```

```
 - Généralités    is 11 chars length, but uses 14 bytes
 - Language       is  8 chars length, but uses  8 bytes
 - Théorème       is  8 chars length, but uses 10 bytes
 - Février        is  7 chars length, but uses  8 bytes
 - Left: ←        is  7 chars length, but uses  9 bytes
 - Yin Yang ☯     is 10 chars length, but uses 12 bytes
```

See further, at ***Useful printf correction tool***, for explanation about this syntax.

##### Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could split `wc`'s ouput directly:

```bash
for string in Généralités Language Théorème Février  "Left: ←" "Yin Yang ☯";do
    read -r chrs byts < <(wc -mc <<<"$string")
    printf " - %-$((14+$byts-chrs))s is %2d chars length, but uses %2d bytes\n" \
        "$string" $((chrs-1)) $((byts-1))
done
```

But having to *fork* to `wc` for each *strings* could consume a lot of system resources, I prefer to use the ***pure bash*** way! Have a look at bottom of this answer to know why!!

#### By using *pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)*

The first idea I had was to change *locales* environment to force bash to consider each characters as bytes:

```bash
myvar='Généralités'
chrlen=${#myvar}
oLang=$LANG oLcAll=$LC_ALL
LANG=C LC_ALL=C
bytlen=${#myvar}
LANG=$oLang LC_ALL=$oLcAll
printf "%s is %d char len, but %d bytes len.\n" "${myvar}" $chrlen $bytlen
```

will render:

```
Généralités is 11 char len, but 14 bytes len.
```

you could even have a look at stored chars:

```bash
myvar='Généralités'
chrlen=${#myvar}
oLang=$LANG oLcAll=$LC_ALL
LANG=C LC_ALL=C
bytlen=${#myvar}
printf -v myreal "%q" "$myvar"
LANG=$oLang LC_ALL=$oLcAll
printf "%s has %d chars, %d bytes: (%s).\n" "${myvar}" $chrlen $bytlen "$myreal"
```

will answer:

```
Généralités has 11 chars, 14 bytes: ($'G\303\251n\303\251ralit\303\251s').
```

**Nota:** According to [Isabell Cowan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368067/length-of-string-in-bash/31009961#comment69945980_31009961), I've added setting to `$LC_ALL` along with `$LANG`.

So function could be:

```bash
strU8DiffLen() {
    local chLen=${#1} LANG=C LC_ALL=C
    return $((${#1}-chLen))
}
```

But surprisingly, this is not the *quickest* way:

#### Same, but without having to play with locales

I *recently* learn `%n` format of `printf` command (builtin):

```bash
myvar='Généralités'
chrlen=${#myvar}
printf -v _ %s%n "$myvar" bytlen
printf "%s is %d char len, but %d bytes len.\n" "${myvar}" $chrlen $bytlen
Généralités is 11 char len, but 14 bytes len.
```

- `printf -v _` tell printf to store result into variable `_` instead of ouptut them on *`STDOUT`*.
- `_` is a garbage variable in this use.
- `%n` tell printf to store byte count of already processed string into variable name at corresponding place in arguments.

Syntax is a little counter-intuitive, but this is very efficient! (further function `strU8DiffLen` is about 2 time quicker by using `printf` than previous version using `local LANG=C`.)

#### Length of an argument, working sample

Argument work same as regular variables

```bash
showStrLen() {
    local -i chrlen=${#1} bytlen
    printf -v _ %s%n "$1" bytlen
    LANG=$oLang LC_ALL=$oLcAll
    printf "String '%s' is %d bytes, but %d chars len: %q.\n" "$1" $bytlen $chrlen "$1"
}
```

will work as

```bash
showStrLen théorème
```

```
String 'théorème' is 10 bytes, but 8 chars len: $'th\303\251or\303\250me'
```

#### Useful `printf` correction tool:

If you:

```bash
for string in Généralités Language Théorème Février  "Left: ←" "Yin Yang ☯";do
    printf " - %-14s is %2d char length\n" "'$string'"  ${#string}
done
```

```
 - 'Généralités' is 11 char length
 - 'Language'     is  8 char length
 - 'Théorème'   is  8 char length
 - 'Février'     is  7 char length
 - 'Left: ←'    is  7 char length
 - 'Yin Yang ☯' is 10 char length
```

Not really *pretty* output!

For this, here is a little function:

```bash
strU8DiffLen() {
    local -i bytlen
    printf -v _ %s%n "$1" bytlen
    return $(( bytlen - ${#1} ))
}
```

or written in one line:

```bash
strU8DiffLen() { local -i _bl;printf -v _ %s%n "$1" _bl;return $((_bl-${#1}));}
```

Then now:

```bash
for string in Généralités Language Théorème Février  "Left: ←" "Yin Yang ☯";do
    strU8DiffLen "$string"
    printf " - %-*s is %2d chars length, but uses %2d bytes\n" \
        $((14+$?)) "'$string'" ${#string} $((${#string}+$?))
  done
```

```
 - 'Généralités'  is 11 chars length, but uses 14 bytes
 - 'Language'     is  8 chars length, but uses  8 bytes
 - 'Théorème'     is  8 chars length, but uses 10 bytes
 - 'Février'      is  7 chars length, but uses  8 bytes
 - 'Left: ←'      is  7 chars length, but uses  9 bytes
 - 'Yin Yang ☯'   is 10 chars length, but uses 12 bytes
```

#### Unfortunely, this is not perfect!

But there left some strange UTF-8 behaviour, like double-spaced chars, zero spaced chars, reverse deplacement and other that could not be as simple...

Have a look at [diffU8test.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/diffU8test.sh) or [diffU8test.sh.txt](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/diffU8test.sh.txt) for more limitations.

### Comparison: *fork to `wc`* vs *pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)*:

Making a little loop of 1'000 *String length* inquiries:

```bash
string="Généralité"
time for i in {1..1000};do strlens=$(echo -n "$string"|wc -mc);done;echo $strlens
```

```
real    0m2.637s
user    0m2.256s
sys 0m0.906s
10 13
```

```bash
string="Généralité"
time for i in {1..1000};do printf -v _ %s%n "$string" bytlen;chrlen=${#string};done;echo $chrlen $bytlen
```

```
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.000s
10 13
```

Hopefully result (*`10 13`*) is same, but execution time differ a lot, something like **500x** quicker using *pure bash*!!

Comment: I appreciate this answer, as file systems impose name limitations in bytes and not characters.

Comment: You may also need to set LC_ALL=C and perhaps others.

Comment: @IsabellCowan In wich case? I think no! You could prefer to use `LC_ALL` but if not used, this is not *needed*. But no other variable have to be used.

Comment: @F.Hauri try this code: /usr/bin/env -i LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 LANG=C bash -c 'v=€; echo ${#v}'  LC_ALL might be unset by default on your system, but it is not on mine.

Comment: @IsabellCowan Yes, see `man 7 locale`, `LC_ALL` have precedence over all others. It's the reason I follow *Debian* rules, having `LC_ALL=` somewhere and change `LANG` only, by default (It could be very usefull to be able to just change `LC_CTIME` or `LC_NUMERIC`)..

Comment: @F.Hauri But, it none the less follows that on some systems your solution will not work, because it leaves LC_ALL alone.  It might work fine on default installs of Debian and it's derivatives, but on others (like Arch Linux) it will fail to give the correct byte length of the string.

Comment: it didn't work for me and i couldn't find out why, i successed using `iconv` like this: `STR=$(printf "$1" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-15)`, and then `${#STR}` worked well

Comment: @F.Hauri `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` I don't have the admin rights on the server, i tried the examples you gave and i always got the byte length. I'm trying this from a `.sh` file encoding in UTF-8..

Comment: thanks for taking something simple and convoluting it :)

Comment: Just to note that UTF8 is a variable width encoding from 1 to 6 bytes cf. other encodings i.e. UTF16 which is a fixed width 2 byte per character.

Comment: A UTF8 encoded Oracle DB instance allows nvarchar2(4000) data types (4000 bytes, each character stored on 1 to 6 bytes) whereas a UTF16 encoded instance only allows for nvarchar2(2000) data types (4000 bytes, 2 bytes per character). Ex. UTF8 string truncation depends on the number of bytes required to store the data which is not necessarily (and most often not the case when dealing with internationalised software) equal to the number of characters.

Comment: @masseyb Yes `☯` and `←` will require 3 bytes, where `é` and `ô` require 2 bytes and `a` or `z` only 1 byte...

Comment: @thistleknot I'm sorry, [對不起](https://translate.google.ch/#auto/fr/%E5%B0%8D%E4%B8%8D%E8%B5%B7) Sometime ***simple*** is just an idea.

Comment: @F.Hauri correct for UTF8. Encoded in UTF16 each character ("☯", "←", "é", "ô", "a" and "z") is encoded with a fixed 2 bytes. If assuming that all text is ASCII then any mention of UTF8 is "good to know" but not necessary for say as it's 8-bit ASCII and the code points are identical in UTF8. Having taken the time to delve into encodings then it's worth while imho to note that the byte count is encoding dependent and there exists a plethora of different encodings.

Comment: @thistleknot previous chinese post warn me about another problem. see posted test script about limitation (bug) of this: [diffU8test.sh.txt](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/diffU8test.sh.txt) or [diffU8test.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/diffU8test.sh)

Comment: You can't necessarily guarantee that the default locale is UTF-8. To make sure you get character length rather than byte length, you may want to set `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` and `LANG=C.UTF-8`.

Comment: @nyuszika7h You're right, anyway, mostly my `strU8DiffLen` will return correct difference. In case current session usr Latin encoding, `strU8DiffLen` will return `0` (alway) wich will be correct too.

Comment: It's worth to mention that the function `strU8DiffLen` will fail if `$(( bytlen - ${#1} ))` is greater than **255**. Why not just `printf` the result and call the function inside a `sub-shell`? Related: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Comment: @F8ER In order to prevent ***forks***. For sample: Trying to replace `return` by  `echo`, adding `OFF=$(strU8DiffLen....)` and replacing `?` by `OFF` in last sample take 10ms in my host, where published proposition do the jobs in 1ms. (10x faster!)

Comment: @F8ER If you mind using `return`, you could replace them by `printf -v ${2:-OFF} %d $(( bytlen - ${#1} ))`, then use `$OFF` or any other variable by specifying his name as second argument.

Answer (score 659):

To get the length of a string stored in a variable, say:

```
myvar="some string"
size=${#myvar}
```

To confirm it was properly saved, `echo` it:

```
$ echo "$size"
11
```

Comment: With UTF-8 stings, you could have a string length **and** a bytes length. [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31009961/1765658)

Comment: You can also use it directly in other parameter expansions - for example in this test I check that `$rulename` starts with the `$RULE_PREFIX` prefix: 
`[ "${rulename:0:${#RULE_PREFIX}}" == "$RULE_PREFIX" ]`

Comment: Could you please explain a bit the expressions of `#myvar` and `{#myvar}`?

Comment: @lerneradams see [Bash reference manual →3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on `${#parameter}`:
_The length in characters of the expanded value of parameter is substituted_.

Answer (score 46):

I wanted the simplest case, finally this is a result:

```
echo -n 'Tell me the length of this sentence.' | wc -m;
36
```

Comment: sorry mate :(  This is bash... the cursed hammer that sees everything as a nail, particularly your thumb.  'Tell me the length of this sentence.' contains 36 characters.  `echo '' | wc -m` => `1`.  You'd need to use `-n`:  `echo -n '' | wc -m` => `0`... in which case it's a good solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Manual page says: 
`-n     do not output the trailing newline`

Answer (score 27):

You can use:

```
MYSTRING="abc123"
MYLENGTH=$(printf "%s" "$MYSTRING" | wc -c)
```

- `wc -c` or `wc --bytes` for byte counts = Unicode characters are counted with 2, 3 or more bytes.
- `wc -m` or `wc --chars` for character counts = Unicode characters are counted single until they use more bytes.

Comment: -c is for bytes. -m is for chars. 
https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/wc-invocation.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/wc.html

Comment: Seriously? a pipe, a subshell and an external command for something that trivial?

Comment: this handles something like `mylen=$(printf "%s" "$HOME/.ssh" | wc -c)` whereas the accepted solution fails and you need to `myvar=$HOME/.ssh` first.

Comment: This isn’t any better than `${#var}`. You still need `LC_ALL` / `LANG` set to an UTF-8 locale, otherwise `-m` will return byte count.

Answer (score 23):

In response to the post starting:

> If you want to use this with command line or function arguments...

with the code:

```
size=${#1}
```

There might be the case where you just want to check for a zero length argument and have no need to store a variable. I believe you can use this sort of syntax:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    #zero length argument 
else
    #non-zero length
fi
```

See [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) and [wooledge](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) for a more complete list of Bash conditional expressions.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use this with command line or function arguments, make sure you use `size=${#1}` instead of `size=${#$1}`. The second one may be  more instinctual but is incorrect syntax.

Comment: Part of the problem with "you can't do <invalid syntax>" is that, that syntax being invalid, it's unclear what a reader should interpret it to mean. `size=${#1}` is certainly valid.

Comment: Well, that's unexpected. I didn't know that #1 was a substitute for $1 in this case.

Comment: It isn't. `#` isn't replacing the `$` -- the `$` outside the braces is still the expansion operator. The `#` is the length operator, as always.

Comment: I've fixed this answer since it is a useful tip but not an exception to the rule - it follows the rule exactly, as pointed out by @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 18):

Using your example provided

```
#KISS (Keep it simple stupid)
size=${#myvar}
echo $size
```

Comment: @Angel The question was about setting a variable to the output of the length command, and this question answers that.

Answer (score 15):

Here is couple of ways to calculate length of variable :

```
echo ${#VAR}
echo -n $VAR | wc -m
echo -n $VAR | wc -c
printf $VAR | wc -m
expr length $VAR
expr $VAR : '.*'
```

and to set the result in another variable just assign above command with back quote into another variable as following:

```
otherVar=`echo -n $VAR | wc -m`   
echo $otherVar
```

http://techopsbook.blogspot.in/2017/09/how-to-find-length-of-string-variable.html

Answer (score 2):

I know that the Q and A's are old enough, but today I faced this task for first time. Usually I used the `${#var}` combination, but it fails with unicode: most text I process with the bash is in Cyrillic...
Based on @atesin's answer, I made short (and ready to be more shortened) function which may be usable for scripting. That was a task which led me to this question: to show some message of variable length in pseudo-graphics box. So, here it is:

```
$ cat draw_border.sh
#!/bin/sh
#based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368067/length-of-string-in-bash
border()
{
local BPAR="$1"
local BPLEN=`echo $BPAR|wc -m`
local OUTLINE=\|\ "$1"\ \|
# line below based on https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/repeat-a-character-in-bash-script-under-linux-unix/
# comment of Bit Twiddler Jun 5, 2021 @ 8:47
local OUTBORDER=\+`head -c $(($BPLEN+1))</dev/zero|tr '\0' '-'`\+
echo $OUTBORDER
echo $OUTLINE
echo $OUTBORDER
}
border "Généralités"
border 'А вот еще одна '$LESSCLOSE' '
border "pure ENGLISH"
```

And what this sample produces:

```
$ draw_border.sh
+-------------+
| Généralités |
+-------------+
+----------------------------------+
| А вот еще одна /usr/bin/lesspipe |
+----------------------------------+
+--------------+
| pure ENGLISH |
+--------------+
```

First example (in French?) was taken from someone's example above.
Second one combines Cyrillic and the value of some variable. Third one is self-explaining: only 1s 1/2 of ASCII chars.

I used `echo $BPAR|wc -m` instead of `printf ...` in order to not rely on if the printf is buillt-in or not.

Above I saw talks about trailing newline and `-n` parameter for `echo`. I did not used it, thus I add only one to the `$BPLEN`. Should I use `-n`, I must add 2.

To explain the difference between `wc -m` and `wc -c`, see the same script with only one minor change: `-m` was replaced with `-c`

```
$ draw_border.sh
+----------------+
| Généralités |
+----------------+
+---------------------------------------------+
| А вот еще одна /usr/bin/lesspipe |
+---------------------------------------------+
+--------------+
| pure ENGLISH |
+--------------+
```

Accented characters in Latin, and most of characters in Cyrillic are two-byte, thus the length of drawn horizontals are greater than the real length of the message.
Hope, it will save some one some time :-)

p.s. Russian text says "here is one more"

p.p.s. Working "two-liner"

```
#!/bin/sh
#based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368067/length-of-string-in-bash
border()
{
# line below based on https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/repeat-a-character-in-bash-script-under-linux-unix/
# comment of Bit Twiddler Jun 5, 2021 @ 8:47
local OUTBORDER=\+`head -c $(( $(echo "$1"|wc -m) +1))</dev/zero|tr '\0' '-'`\+
echo $OUTBORDER"\n"\|\ "$1"\ \|"\n"$OUTBORDER
}
border "Généralités"
border 'А вот еще одна '$LESSCLOSE' '
border "pure ENGLISH"
```

In order to not clutter the code with repetitive OUTBORDER's drawing, I put the forming of OUTBORDER into separate command

Comment: Shorter and a lot quicker: `border() { local sline;printf -v sline '%*s' ${#1} '';printf '+%s+\n|%s|\n+%s+\n' ${sline// /-} "$1" ${sline// /-};}`  - Have a look at bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31009961/1765658) : upto 500x faster!'... Or even try this: `border() { local line sline;for line;do printf -v sline '%*s' ${#line} '';printf '+%s+\n|%s|\n+%s+\n' ${sline// /-} "$line" ${sline// /-};done;}` then `border 'généralité' 'А вот еще одна /usr/bin/lesspipe' 'pure ENGLISH'`

Comment: About `${#var}`, take care of `$LC_ALL` and **your** locales configuration: compare: `border() { local LC_ALL=C.UTF8 line sline;for line;do printf -v sline '%*s' ${#line} '';printf '+%s+\n|%s|\n+%s+\n' ${sline// /-} "$line" ${sline// /-};done;}` with `border() { local LC_ALL=C line sline;for line;do printf -v sline '%*s' ${#line} '';printf '+%s+\n|%s|\n+%s+\n' ${sline// /-} "$line" ${sline// /-};done;}` ... (depending on **your** configuration, you may have to replace `C.UTF8` by `ru_RU.UTF-8`, `zh_CN.UTF-8` or else... Try: `grep '^[^#]*UTF' /etc/locale.gen`)

Comment: ... And, still abount `${#var}`, the only *shell* that won't consider U8 characters correctly is `dash`, U could test: `for shell in dash bash busybox\ sh zsh ;do echo -n $shell : \ ;$shell -c 'echo ${#1}' -- 'Généralité';done`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just use `wc -c` to count the number of characters:

```bash
myvar="Hello, I am a string."
echo -n $myvar | wc -c
```

Result:

```bash
21
```

Answer (score 0):

> Length of string in bash

```
str="Welcome to Stackoveflow"  
length=`expr length "$str"`  
  
echo "Length of '$str' is $length"
```

> OUTPUT

Length of 'Welcome to Stackoveflow' is 23