# How to find the length of special characters in linux

Tags: linux

```
str1 = "LIMITEDESCRITøRIO" 
str2 = "RITøRIO"
str3 = "øRIO"
echo "Length = $str1 $str2 $str3"

Result: 
Length = 13 4 1
```

Length is getting calculated only till the occurrence of special character. And the rest are ignored.

Can anyone pls explain the reason behind this and also give me the solution to calculate the length of full string that contains special character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of string in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368067/length-of-string-in-bash)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Which shell are you using? The syntax you wrote does not work in most shells. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Well it clearly can't be bash - there are spaces around the "=", the Result would be just those strings, not their lengths, however wrong. It's not perl either.. maybe PHP (I have almost no experience with PHP)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$ str1="LIMITEDESCRITøRIO"
$ len=${#str1}
$ echo "Length of string \"${str1}\" is ${len}."

Length of string "LIMITEDESCRITøRIO" is 17.
```