# Length comparison of one specific field in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I was trying to check the length of second field of a TSV file (hundreds of thousands of lines).  However, it runs very very slowly. I guess it should be something wrong with "echo", but not sure how to do.

Input file:

```
prob    name
1.0     Claire
1.0     Mark
...     ...
0.9     GFGKHJGJGHKGDFUFULFD
```

So I need to print out what went wrong in the name. I tested with a little example using "head -100" and it worked.  But just can't cope with original file.

This is what I ran:

```
for title in `cat filename | cut -f2`;do
length=`echo -n $line | wc -m`
if [ "$length" -gt 10 ];then
echo $line
fi
done
```

Comment: add a testable fragment of your `filename` and the final expected output

Comment: Have a look [there: Length of string in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31009961/1765658)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to rescue:

```
awk 'length($2)>10' file
```

This will print all lines having the second field length longer than 10 characters.

Note that it doesn't require any block statement `{...}` because if the condition is met, `awk` will by default print the line.

Comment: Your script is correct but a few words to explain would be useful. Otherwise, your answer may as well be "`awk` to the rescue, and ask again on Stack Overflow next time you want to do anything".

Comment: Thanks! I don't really know about awk, but it seems quite useful. I'll learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this probably:

```
cat file.tsv | awk '{if (length($2) > 10) print $0;}'
```

This should be a bit faster since the whole processing is done by the single `awk` process, while your solution starts 2 processes per loop iteration to make that comparison.

Comment: It will be a lot faster. But you should remove the useless use of `cat`, and like I said to Shravan, everything except `length($2) > 10` is unnecessary.

Comment: @TomFenech Sure, just to be perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use awk if that helps.

```
awk '{if(length($2) > 10){print}}' filename
```

$2 here is 2nd field in filename which runs for every line. It would be faster.

Comment: Everything except `length($2) > 10` is unnecessary in that awk script.