# bash + for loop + output index number and element

Tags: arrays, bash, printf

This is my array:

```
$ ARRAY=(one two three)
```

How do I print the array so I have the output like: `index i, element[i]` using the `printf` or `for` loop I use below

```
1,one
2,two
3,three
```

Some notes for my reference

1 way to print the array:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${ARRAY[*]}"
one two three
```

2 way to print the array

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${ARRAY[@]}"
one
two
three
```

3 way to print the array

```
$ for elem in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do  echo "$elem"; done
one
two
three
```

4 way to print the array

```
$ for elem in "${ARRAY[*]}"; do  echo "$elem"; done
one two three
```

A nothe way to look at the array

```
$ declare -p ARRAY
declare -a ARRAY='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can iterate over the indices of the array, i.e. from `0` to `${#array[@]} - 1`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

array=(one two three)

# ${#array[@]} is the number of elements in the array
for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; ++i)); do
    # bash arrays are 0-indexed
    position=$(( $i + 1 ))
    echo "$position,${array[$i]}"
done
```

**Output**

```
1,one
2,two
3,three
```

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way to iterate seems to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

array=(one two three)

# ${!array[@]} is the list of all the indexes set in the array
for i in ${!array[@]}; do
  echo "$i, ${array[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for your shortest solution to answer exactly to the initial request, code should be :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

array=(one two three)
for i in ${!array[@]}; do
  echo "$(($i+1)), ${array[$i]}"
done
```

... in order to print element number starting from 1, not zero.

`$(($i+1))` is a Bash compound `$(( ))` command of "arithmetic expansion" for evaluation of arithmetic expressions.