# bash loop mysql output multiple to variables

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, loops, variables

new to programming and need a little help.

I need to access a MySQL database and loop thru the ‘ftpuser’ and ‘domain’ column to give me the output below

```
echo 2>&1 " 3cmd put -r /home/$ftpuser/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/$domainname/"
```

when I run the shell script below it outputs ever user with each domain

```
 3cmd put -r /home/user1/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain1.com/
 3cmd put -r /home/user1/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain2.com
 3cmd put -r /home/user1/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain3.com/
 3cmd put -r /home/user2/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain1.com/
 3cmd put -r /home/user2/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain2.com/
 3cmd put -r /home/user2/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain3.com/
```

and so on

the result im looking for is

```
 3cmd put -r /home/user1/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain1.com/
 3cmd put -r /home/user2/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain2.com/
 3cmd put -r /home/user3/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain3.com/
 3cmd put -r /home/user4/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain4.com/
```

here is the code

## !/bin/bash

```
filelines=username=$(mysql -h localhost -u root -p -ss -e "use users; SELECT ftpuser FROM users; ")

filelines2=username=$(mysql -h localhost -u root -p -ss -e "use users; SELECT domain FROM users; ")

echo Start

for username in $filelines ; do

for domainname in $filelines2 ; do

echo 2>&1 " 3cmd put -r /home/$username/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/$domainname/"

done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the elements of `filelines` , `filelines2` in separate bash arrays and loop once through the index as shown.

```
arr1=($filelines)
arr2=($filelines2)
for i in ${!arr1[@]}
 do
   echo 2>&1 " 3cmd put -r /home/${arr1[$i]}/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/${arr2[$i]}/"
done
```

**Output:**

```
 3cmd put -r /home/user1/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain1/
 3cmd put -r /home/user2/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain2/
 3cmd put -r /home/user3/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain3/
 3cmd put -r /home/user4/backups/ s3://bucket-backup/domain4/
```

You can refer [Looping over arrays, printing both index and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723426/looping-over-arrays-printing-both-index-and-value) for understanding the looping syntax.

Comment: You r welcome.could u pls mark this as the best answer. Thanks

Comment: Just did. Thanks again