# loop over output of command and print both index and value

Tags: bash

I have checked [Looping over arrays, printing both index and value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723516/1772898). The issue is I want to loop over output of command and not an array.

The code i came up with is:

```
array=($(seq 1 10))

for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array[$i]}"
done
```

or,

```
ITER=0
for I in $(seq 1 10)
do  
    echo ${I} ${ITER}
    ITER=$(expr $ITER + 1)
done
```

What i want to know is, is it possible to do it within the loop only (without `array` or `ITER`) outside the loop?

What i am looking for is something like:

```
for index,value in $(seq 1 10); do
  echo $index $value
done
```

Comment: If you need a running index, you have to calculate it manually. Also, it is unclear what exactly you mean by _loop over output_. From the code snippets you posted, I infer that you mean to _loop over the individual words which a command writes to standard output_, but it's better to state this precisely when asking such a question.

Comment: This is what you already said. But the words "loop over output" does not have a real meaning. Should each iteration of the loop consume one character of the output, or one word of the output, or whatever? In your example, you are looping over the words in stdout of the command, and if this is really what you want to achieve in the general case, you better state this explicitly.

Comment: Neither the code you posted nor the text in your question says this. Furthermore, if you google for this problem, you will find many suggestions, so it's not clear to me at which point you are stuck.

Comment: Try the search term _stackoverflow bash read file by line_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us know your actual requirement:

```
01)
#!/bin/bash
index=0
for filename in $(ls -atr)
do
        indx=$(($indx+1))
        echo "Index: $indx $filename"
done
```

output:

```
$  ./73412398.sh
Index: 1 ..
Index: 2 73412398.sh
Index: 3 .
```

One more try:

```
for index in $(ls -atr | grep -n $)
do
 echo $index | sed "s/\([0-9]*\):/\1 /;"
done
```

output:

```
1 ..
2 73412398.sh
3 .
```

Comment: After fixing your first answer it worked. There are many typos in the first one. Probably you pasted the wrong thing. The second one is what i needed.

Comment: I posted a response after taking hint from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

after modifying murugesan openssl's answer, the solution for me is:

```
for indexval in $(ls -atr | grep -n $)
do
 echo index is "${indexval%%:*}"
 echo value is "${indexval#*:}"
done
```